# How to use Laravel Task Schedule out of framework?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way (framework, library) to use Task Schedule just the way Laravel works?
Or a way to extract only that funcionality from Laravel Framework?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel really isn't designed to be split up like Symfony and their components.  You could try installing `illuminate/events` and `illuminate/console` and resolving the task scheduler's dependencies.

Task scheduling involves using the `artisan schedule:run` command, so you'd need to reverse engineer the code starting from `Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand`.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible, look at this

[illuminate-schedule](https://github.com/millancore/illuminate-schedule)

All you need is to create a custom Application. The Application is in instance of `illuminate/container` on which all the characteristics of the framework depend.

Comment: isn't this a bit like installing Laravel in a sub folder?

Comment: The load is much better since Application only loads the necessary classes and not the entire framework.